# Python 3.6: 'elif' statements ruining word swap function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my program to return a print statement if parameters b or c are not found in the string provided. But when I add it, it looks like this:

```
Not in string: dylan
Not in string: dylan
Not in string: dylan
BOB  DYLAN  .
Not in string: BOB
Not in string: BOB
Not in string: BOB
BOB  DYLAN  .
Not in string: dylan
Not in string: dylan
Not in string: dylan
 DYLAN  .
Not in string: DYLAN
Not in string: DYLAN
Not in string: DYLAN
BOB   .
```

Taking 2 elif statements out, however, gets me half of the desired output:

```
BOB and DYLAN work together. # good
BOB and DYLAN work together. #good
Not in string: "dylan" #desired output
Not in string: "BoB" #desired ouput
```

Here is the function that I've made:

```
import re

def swapfunc(a,b,c):
    def func(m):
        g = m.group(1).lower()
        if g == c.lower():
            return b.upper()
        elif g == b.lower():
            return c.upper()
        #elif b not in a: # Adding these 2 elif's screw up the function entirely
            #return print("Not in string:" , b)
        #elif c not in a:
            #return print("Not in string:" , c)        
        else:
            return m.group(1)

    return re.sub("(\w+)",func,a)

print(swapfunc("Dylan and Bob work together.", "dylan", "bob")) # this is good
print(swapfunc("Dylan and Bob work together.", "BOB", "DylAn")) #this is good     
print(swapfunc("and Bob work together.", "dylan", "bob"))
# Not in string: "dylan" <-- should be the output
print(swapfunc("Dylan and work together.", "DYLAN", "BoB"))
# Not in string: "BoB"  <-- should be the output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my suggestion

```
import re

def swapfunc(text, b, c):
    if re.search(r"\b"+b+r"\b|\b"+c+r"\b", text, re.I):

        if not re.search(r"\b"+b+r"\b", text, re.I):
            return b+" not found";
        elif not re.search(r"\b"+c+r"\b", text, re.I):
            return c+" not found";
        else:
            text = re.sub(r"\b"+b+r"\b", '__c__', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            text = re.sub(r"\b"+c+r"\b", '__b__', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            text = text.replace('__c__', c.upper())
            text = text.replace('__b__', b.upper())
            return text
    else:
        return "Values "+b+" and "+c+" not found";

print(swapfunc("dylan and Bob work together.", "Dylan", "bob"))
print(swapfunc("Dylan and Bob work together.", "BOB", "DylAn"))
print(swapfunc("and Bob work together.", "dylan", "bob"))
print(swapfunc("Dylan and work together.", "DYLAN", "BoB"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `elif` tests are applied to *each and every single word individually*, because you call `fun` via `re.sub('(\w+)')`.

So no, `dylan` is not in your sentence, but this test is executed for each of the words, *separately*. There are 4 separate words in the string `"and Bob work together."`, so you test 4 times, and print 4 times. Also, because you return `None` (the result of the `print()` function) in those cases, you tell `re.sub()` to remove the matched word altogether.

You'd need to run those tests *separately first*, before using `re.sub()`:

```
if b not in a:
    print("Not in string:", b)
    return

if c not in a:
    print("Not in string:", c)
    return

return re.sub("(\w+)", func, a)
```